# Add an exit proxy to Tor

Tags: socks, website, proxy

I am confuse about how to edit torrc file to add a proxy after tor. I saw that I have to edit the .torrc to do so, but adding a socks4/5 proxy remains unclear, either on the tor manual, or others websites.

I want to do so to access website that recongnise tor users and dismiss them. For linux commands, I use to edit the proxychains-ng (by rofl0r) configuration file and it was straightforward but for browsers...

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported by Tor or the Tor Browser. You will most likely have to come up with a solution yourself. A workaround might be pointing Tor Browser at your proxychained Tor.

Comment: Ok so after edit proxychains.conf, I would type : sudo proxychains torbrowser Or, if all my traffic is currently routing via tor : sudo proxychains firefox/chrome Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

To pot a proxy AFTER Tor, i.e. to make Tor use proxy to connect to the outside world use :

- HTTPProxy + HTTPProxyAuthenticator username:password
- HTTPSProxy + HTTPSProxyAuthenticator username:password
- Socks4Proxy
- Socks5Proxy + Socks5ProxyPassword password

as it's clearly said in the [official FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#NeedToUseAProxy)